# Scala: wake up sleeping thread

Tags: multithreading, scala

In scala, how can I tell a thread: sleep t seconds, or until you receive a message? i.e. sleep  at most t seconds, but wake up in case t is not over and you receive a certain message.

Comment: IIRC, there is a wait(long timeout) overload?  If so, wait on some object and notify() if a message is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatively, you can use condition variables.

```
val monitor = new AnyRef
var messageReceived: Boolean = false

// The waiting thread...

def waitUntilMessageReceived(timeout: Int): Boolean = {
    monitor synchronized {
        // The time-out handling here is simplified for the purpose
        // of exhibition. The "wait" may wake up spuriously for no
        // apparent reason. So in practice, this would be more complicated,
        // actually.
        while (!messageReceived) monitor.wait(timeout * 1000L)
        messageReceived
    }
}

// The thread, which sends the message...

def sendMessage: Unit = monitor synchronized {
    messageReceived = true
    monitor.notifyAll
}
```

Comment: But the random wake-ups problem should be dealt with by having while(!messageReceived) and not if(!messageReceived), shouldn't it?

Comment: Rolling this sort of solution by hand is highly inadvisable unless you have no choice (e.g. because peformance is critical and the necessary logic is nonstandard)--it's too easy to forget something.  There are higher-level constructs within Scala and Java that should be used instead.

Comment: @user1377000 - the random wake-ups are handled by the `while`, but the time-out behaviour would be wrong in my proposal: after each wake-up, the time-out would start again with the initial value. In the worst case, this can lead to a "wait forever" scenario.

Answer (score 3):

The answer depends greatly on what the message *is*.  If you're using Actors (either the old variety or the [Akka variety](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html)) then you can simply state a timeout value on receive.  (React isn't really running until it gets a message, so you can't place a timeout on it.)

```
// Old style
receiveWithin(1000) {
  case msg: Message => // whatever
  case TIMEOUT =>      // Handle timeout
}

// Akka style
context.setTimeoutReceive(1 second)
def receive = {
  case msg: Message =>   // whatever
  case ReceiveTimeout => // handle timeout
}
```

Otherwise, what exactly do you mean by "message"?

One easy way to send a message is to use the Java concurrent classes made for exactly this kind of thing.  For example, you can use a `java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue` to hold the message, and the receiver can call the `poll` method which takes a timeout:

```
// Common variable
val q = new java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue[String]

// Waiting thread
val msg = q.poll(1000)

// Sending thread will also block until receiver is ready to take it
q.offer("salmon", 1000)
```

An `ArrayBlockingQueue` is also useful in these situations (if you want the senders to be able to pack messages in a buffer).

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Await](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Await%24). If you have some [Awaitable](http://www.scala-lang.org/archives/downloads/distrib/files/nightly/docs/library/index.html#scala.concurrent.Awaitable) objects then that's what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making it sleep for a given time, make it only wake up on a Timeout() msg and then you can send this message prematurely if you want it to "wake up".